# Getting all errors from go vet with cgo

Tags: go, cgo

`go vet` and `go build` normally stop after finding 10 errors and abort with "`too many errors`" when run on a cgo codebase:

```
$ go version
go version go1.10 linux/amd64

$ go vet loremipsum
src/loremipsum/foo.go:103: invalid operation: _Ctype__Bool(IS_OK(c)) && IS_EVIL(c) (mismatched types _Ctype__Bool and bool)
# 9 other vet issues
src/loremipsum/foo.go:203: too many errors
```

The project is large enough that each of these commands takes ~minutes to run, so I'd prefer to get a complete list of issues all at once.

I can achieve this with `go build` by passing `-gcflags "-e"` (https://menno.io/posts/showing-all-go-compiler-errors/)

How can I do the same for `go vet` (which doesn't take a `-gcflags` parameter!)

Comment: `go vet` doesn't stop at 10 messages, it finds and prints all. How are you runnig it?

Comment: @icza I mean, it really does for me- running it with `go vet $packagename`, as stated

Comment: Can you create a single file, put an `f()` function in it, and put 20 `return` statements in its body. Then run `go vet` on this package. This should give 19 messages ("unreachable code"). Do you get 19 messages?

Comment: Also, can you pass `-v` to vet, so it may display errors why it stops? `go vet -v`

Comment: Right, I suspect this is cgo related, thanks - I indeed got 19 messages out of the single pure Go file; `go vet -v` gives me no extra useful info